# Selecting an item with multiple conditions from a list using Espresso

Tags: android, layout, android-espresso

I'm trying to select an item from a list using Espresso.

It should be pretty straightforward, but I need to select an item with multiple conditions.

The conditions are:

task.getLocation != null;
task.getCurrentStatus == Task.ASSIGNED;

So using atPosition() won't work. The items in the list are constantly changing.

My sad attempt:

```
onData(new BoundedMatcher<Object, Task>(Task.class) {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(Task item) {
        return (item.getLocation() != null && item.getCurrentStatus() == Task.ASSIGNED);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
    }

}).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listView)).perform(click());
```

I took it from Dinesh VG's answer here:

[Espresso onData perform click on multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813336/espresso-ondata-perform-click-on-multiple-items)

But if I use the complete given example, it doesn't work. It does not accept allOf() nor is().

I also tried other approaches as well, pretty unsuccessfully.

The stack trace:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.
For more info check: -------

with id: com.sentilant.driviantasks:id/listView'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:82)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:79)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:51)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:173)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:114)
at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction$DisplayDataMatcher$1.apply(DataInteraction.java:213)
at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction$DisplayDataMatcher$1.apply(DataInteraction.java:210)
at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction$DisplayDataMatcher.<init>(DataInteraction.java:230)
at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction$DisplayDataMatcher.<init>(DataInteraction.java:205)
at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction$DisplayDataMatcher.displayDataMatcher(DataInteraction.java:248)
at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction.makeTargetMatcher(DataInteraction.java:150)
at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction.perform(DataInteraction.java:135)
at com.sentilant.driviantasks.TestMapMasterUI.testLayoutWithTask(TestMapMasterUI.java:201)
at com.sentilant.driviantasks.TestMapMasterUI.NavigationLayoutTests(TestMapMasterUI.java:73)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple data elements matched: . Elements: [Data: com.sentilant.driviantasks.api.task.Task@bb69b92 (class: com.sentilant.driviantasks.api.task.Task) token: 17, Data: com.sentilant.driviantasks.api.task.Task@61edede (class: com.sentilant.driviantasks.api.task.Task) token: 18]
at android.support.test.espresso.action.AdapterDataLoaderAction.perform(AdapterDataLoaderAction.java:125)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:356)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:248)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:63)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:153)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please post a stacktrace?

Comment: I could, but there is not much to show. It only complains about animation timing (which I'm taking into account, of course).

Comment: Oh what the heck. Stack trace posted ;)

Comment: Actually, your matcher is working correctly because it's saying there're multiple matches - Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple data elements matched:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace it looks like your matcher is working correctly :) it's just that there are multiple matches - `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple data elements matched: . Elements:`

You could write a matcher that selects the first result out of a set of results:

```
public static <T> Matcher<T> first(final Matcher<T> matcher) {
    return new BaseMatcher<T>() {
        private boolean firstSelected = false;
        @Override
        public boolean matches(final Object item) {
            if (!firstSelected && matcher.matches(item)) {
                firstSelected = true;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
        }
    };
}
```

And then use it as the following:

```
onData(first(new BoundedMatcher<Object, Task>(Task.class) {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(Task item) {
        return (item.getLocation() != null && item.getCurrentStatus() == Task.ASSIGNED);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
    }

})).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listView)).perform(click());
```

For `onData` it could be even simpler by using `atPosition`:

```
onData(<your matcher>).inAdapterView(<adapter view ID>).atPosition(0).perform(click());
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Do you know how to select the very first one from the returned list?

Comment: I edited my answer showing how to select the first result.

Comment: @LuísHenriques I edited my answer with a second simpler option :)